# sync controller with change in service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angular-services

I'm new to Angular and started building an RSS-Feed App. When a user clicks on a Feed link, I'd like to populate a view that lists all the Feed's entries. I have a FeedsCtrl (displays feed titles), an EntriesCtrl (displays all entries associated with a feed), and a service used to communicate between the two.

The problem is I can't get the EntriesCtrl to update the view when a user clicks on a Feed link. Here are snapshots of what I have:

feeds.html.erb:

```html
<div class="feed-index-wrapper" ng-controller="FeedsCtrl">
 <ul class="feed-group list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item" 
  ng-repeat="feed in feeds">
   <a ng-click="fetchEntries(feed.id)">{{ feed.title }}</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

entries.html.erb:

```html
<div class="entries-index-wrapper" ng-controller="EntriesCtrl">
 <ul class="entry-group list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item" 
  ng-repeat="entry in entries">
   {{ entry.title }}
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

services/feed.js:

```js
App.factory('Feed', ['$resource', function($resource){
 return $resource('/api/feeds/:id', { id: '@id' })
}]);
```

services/entry.js:

```js
App.service('Entry', ['$resource', function($resource){
 return {
  preview: [{ title: "Preview "}],
  resource: $resource('/api/feeds/:id/entries', { id: '@id' }),
 }
}]);
```

controllers/feeds_ctrl.js:

```js
App.controller('FeedsCtrl', function($scope, Feed, Entry) {
 $scope.feeds = Feed.query();

 $scope.fetchEntries = function(id) {
  Entry.resource.query({ id: id }, function(entries) {
   Entry.preview = entries;
  });
 }
});
```

controllers/entries_ctrl.js:

```js
App.controller('EntriesCtrl', function($scope, Entry) {
 $scope.entries = Entry.preview;
});
```

app.js:

```js
App = angular.module('TheDailyRead', [
 'ngResource', 
 'ui.router', 
 'templates',
 'ngRoute'
 ]);

App.config(function($routeProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
 $routeProvider.otherwise('/');

 $stateProvider
  .state('feeds', {
   url: '/',
   views: {
    '': {
    templateUrl: 'feeds.html',
    controller: 'FeedsCtrl',
    },
    'new-feed': {
     templateUrl: 'new.html',
     controller: 'NewFeedCtrl',
    },
    'entries': {
     templateUrl: 'entries.html',
     controllers: 'EntriesCtrl'
    } 
   }
  });
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

I've tried applying solutions from other answers from Stack Overflow, but haven't had much luck. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure `Entry.preview = entries;` is called in `function $scope.fetchEntries` and appropriate data is passed.
2. Call $scope.$apply() after `Entry.preview = entries;`

Hope it helps!

P.S. if it doesn't help, try $scope.$watch, read more in [AngularJS Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your scope entries in the service call callback (`$scope.entries = Entry.preview`), so this:

```
App.controller('FeedsCtrl', function($scope, Feed, Entry) {
    $scope.feeds = Feed.query();

    $scope.fetchEntries = function(id) {
        Entry.resource.query({ id: id }, function(entries) {
            Entry.preview = entries;
        });
    }
});
```

Should become this:

```
App.controller('FeedsCtrl', function($scope, Feed, Entry) {
    $scope.feeds = Feed.query();

    $scope.fetchEntries = function(id) {
        Entry.resource.query({ id: id }, function(entries) {
            $scope.entries = Entry.preview = entries; // <--- here
            // force a scope digest if needed
            $scope.apply();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I appreciate your help! I inputted the line $scope.entries = Entry.preview = entries, but the Entries Ctrl/Entries.html.erb is still not updating for some reason. Also tested $scope.$apply(), but it doesn't look like it's needed - I get a "$digest already in progress" error. Can you think of anything else I can tweak/change to get results?

Comment: Hmmm, try exposing the scope to the window object and change it manually from the console... If that works, try wrapping the $scope.entries=Entry.preview part in a $timeout callback.

Answer (score 0):

May not be the most elegant way, but I was able to get this to work by grabbing the div class containing the entries controller and accessing the scope of that div. Like this:

```js
App.controller('FeedsCtrl', function($scope, Feed, Entry) {
 $scope.feeds = Feed.query();

 $scope.fetchEntries = function(id) {
  Entry.resource.query({ id: id }, function(entries) {
   var entriesWrapper = $('.entries-index-wrapper').scope();
   Entry.preview = entriesWrapper.entries = entries;
  });
 }
});
```